# Injecting property file values into Controller via Spring not working

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Hoping you may be able to help.  My Spring knowledge is extremely limited to apologies if the solution is something really obvious.

Here are the contents of the relevant files:

application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <util:properties id="messageConfig" location="classpath:customMessages.properties"/>

</beans>
```

/src/main/resources/customMessages.properties:

```
sms.message=Test
```

Java class:

```
@Controller
public class ApiRestController implements ApiRest {
    @Value("#{messageConfig['sms.message']}")
    private String smsMessage;

    public final void setSmsMessage (String smsMessage)
    {
        this.smsMessage = smsMessage;
    }

    ...
}
```

However, when referencing the 'smsMessage' variable elsewhere in the Java class, the value is NULL.  Any ideas what I might be missing?  Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling this controller?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="spring-controllers-package"/>
```

to the **application-context.xml**

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.  I have added this to application-context.xml (replacing "spring-controllers-package" with the package that my controller is in) but I am still seeing the same issue unfortunately.